# MySQL strange error in CREATE ... SELECT: ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

This is the problematic query (with the intended meaning: pull all entities paired with entity 530 into a new table, with the count of the pairs):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE paired (
  entity_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  numrels INTEGER
)
SELECT I.entity2_id, COUNT(I.relation_id) AS numrels
FROM pairs I
WHERE I.entity1_id = 530 AND I.entity2_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY I.entity2_id
;
```

I interpret the error message:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 1
```

as the complaint that I am violating primary key's uniqueness. However, I am *grouping* by that value, which should ensure the uniqueness, right? Then I thought to try this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE paired (
  entity_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  numrels INTEGER
)
;
INSERT INTO paired
SELECT I.entity2_id, COUNT(I.relation_id) AS numrels
FROM pairs I
WHERE I.entity1_id = 530 AND I.entity2_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY I.entity2_id
;
```

Surprisingly enough, this works without any problems, even though, according to my understanding, the two should be equivalent.

What gives?!?

For reference:

```
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.82sp1, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: Are the id values that you get unique? Can you post some example data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statements are not equivalent. `CREATE ... SELECT` creates the columns you mention in the `CREATE` part of the statement (that is, entity_id and numrels), and in addition creates columns for each column of the `SELECT` part of the statement. You end up with four columns in your new table. The results of `SELECT` are inserted into the last two columns. The other columns are filled with their default values, which results in violating the uniqueness of your primary key.

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: Thank you! Not quite correct, but correct enough that I understood what was happening. More precisely: I have another similar query, and that one works. The reason is, the query before had `entity_id` in both `SELECT` and `CREATE`; in this one, I have `entity2_id`. If the column names are the same, they are conflated. Thus, I had two columns in that one, but three in this one (`entity_id`, `numrels`, `entity2_id`). :D